# Is Resharper unnecessarily warning me about Access to modified closure here?

Tags: linq, resharper

...so I have this code:

```
        foreach (var entry in list)
        {
            var marginOneEntry = otherList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Margin == entry.Margin);                
            if (marginOneEntry == null) continue;
            // Do stuff with marginOneEntry
        }
```

and Resharper 5.1 warns me about "access to modified closure" for the use of `entry` in the compare-statement in the lambda expression. Isn't the FirstOrDefault-call cancelling this issue? Is my code bad or is this warning just a shortcoming in Resharper?

Note: I have read other topics on Access to modified closure here on SO, but I want an answer for this specific case, and to get clarified whether or not Resharper is overly sensitive on this subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is an issue in Resharper since it doesn't distinguish methods with lazy evaluated result from methods which do not use given lambda in lazy evaluation. `FirstOrDefault` doesn't do lazy evaluation (forgot the term opposite to 'lazy') so it safe to use it in your example but usually there is no way to understand that from method's signature.

Comment: The term opposite to lazy would be eager.

Answer (score 3):

I think you made a mistake in the code above. Your `.Where(p => entry.Margin == 1)` precondition does not involve the element being enumerated. Did you mean `p.Margin == 1` instead?

Also, instead of writing `x.Where(y).FirstOrDefault()` you can simply write `x.FirstOrDefault(y)`.

Comment: Regarding FirstOrDefault: Thanks, I've changed that. But I did mean to access the entry-variable in the Where clause. That's why Resharper is reacting. I've changed the code snippet to be more realistic now, though. Assume we have two lists with the same kind of entities - `list`  and `otherlist`